# Antlr4 Performance Issue in ECMAScript 6 grammar

Tags: antlr4

I'm writing grammar for ECMAScript 6. The grammar is written in two files: [lexer grammar](http://hg.netbeans.org/web-main/raw-file/58824541d191/javascript2.editor/tools/ECMAScript6ColoringTokens.g4) and [parser grammar](http://hg.netbeans.org/web-main/raw-file/58824541d191/javascript2.editor/tools/ECMAScript6.g4).

The generated parser works OK, but the performance is very bad. It's big difference between the first parsing and the next parsing in a cycle. For example the first parsing with LL prediction mode of prototype.js file ( ~2 500 lines) currently takes about 8-12 seconds and the next parsing takes about 890 - 990 ms on my machine. Before some grammar optimisations it took around 58 seconds the first parsing and 7 seconds the second parsing.  When I try SLL parser, as is advised to obtain better performance, then even after 30 minutes the first parsing is not finished, so probably the parse is in an endless cycle. I would like to get time something about 400 ms in this case.

When esvalidate.js file is parsed, which has 200 lines than the first LL parsing usually takes 1.6 - 1.9 seconds and the second LL parsing takes around 260ms. When the parser is switched to prediction mode SLL, then the first parsing is finished about 16 seconds (ten time more then with LL prediction mode), but the second parsing takes only 70ms.

Could we somehow speed up the first parsing?
Why the first SLL parsing take so much time? And even in the case of prototype.js is not finished after 30 minutes? Any advice, which will help me to solve this problem is welcome.

I use antlr 4.5.1. for generating and running the parser.

Thanks for every hint.